# C# ASP.NET MVC- How do I post data of two different models from a single Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, registration

I have two models, User and Employee. I have to make a registration form, where I'll be taking inputs for both these models. I know how to do this with a single model but I cannot figure out how to do it for multiple models. I have read some suggestions here where they've suggested using a ViewModel but I cannot configure it properly.

User:

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Employee:

```
public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UserEmployee
    {
        public UserModel user { get; set; }
        public EmployeeModel emp { get; set; }
    }
```

My controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RegisterEmployee()
        {

            var model = new UserEmployee();
            model.user = new UserModel();
            model.emp = new EmployeeModel();
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterEmployee(UserEmployee useremp)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Form:

```
@model ZeroHungerProject.Models.UserEmployee
///////
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>User Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="@Model.user.UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="@Model.user.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Phone</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="@Model.emp.Phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="@Model.user.Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30">Register</button>
```

I tried using the viewmodel to post the inputs. But no data is passing from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefix "@Model." from the `name` attribute.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="user.UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="user.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="number" name="emp.Phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="user.Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30">Register</button>
</form>
```

[image]

And to pass `ConfirmPassword`, you need to provide the `name` attribute to the `<input>` element for `ConfirmPassword` and add the `ConfirmPassword` property in the `UserModel` class.

```
<input type="password" name="user.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
```

```cs
public class UserModel
{
    ...

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```